# Hand Segmentation in EmguCV

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am new to Image Recognition and EmguCV. I want to detect hand in image frames captured by webcam, preferably in binary form, and ideally removing all the background from the frame itself.

I've tried several Haar Cascades but recently I came to know that Haar Cascades are only trained to detect specific hand positions, it can not detect "any" gesture of hands. So, I am now studying ways to extract human skin from a frame (I've succeeded in this part), and then extracting the hands from it. The problem is, I've given a skin color range to detection code but since it overlaps with many other objects, such as walls, I need some help removing those parts. Moreover, ideally, I would also like to strip off other body parts such as face as well, leaving with pure binary image of hand.

Here is the code that I have for skin detection, grabbed from http://blog.csdn.net/scyscyao/archive/2010/04/09/5468577.aspx

```
public Image<Gray, byte> DetectSkin(Image<Bgr, byte> img)
{
    Image<Ycc, byte> currentYCrCbFrame = img.Convert<Ycc, byte>();
    Image<Gray, byte> skin = new Image<Gray, byte>(img.Width, img.Height);

    int y, cr, cb, l, x1, y1, value;

    int rows = img.Rows;
    int cols = img.Cols;
    byte[,,] YCrCbData = currentYCrCbFrame.Data;
    byte[,,] skinData = skin.Data;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            y = YCrCbData[i, j, 0];
            cr = YCrCbData[i, j, 1];
            cb = YCrCbData[i, j, 2];

            cb -= 109;
            cr -= 152;
            x1 = (819 * cr - 614 * cb) / 32 + 51;
            y1 = (819 * cr + 614 * cb) / 32 + 77;
            x1 = x1 * 41 / 1024;
            y1 = y1 * 73 / 1024;
            value = x1 * x1 + y1 * y1;
            if (y < 100)
                skinData[i, j, 0] = (value < 700) ? (byte)255 : (byte)0;
            else
                skinData[i, j, 0] = (value < 850) ? (byte)255 : (byte)0;
        }
    }
    // Below 3 lines attempt to remove the extra objects a little bit but fails to do s0
    Mat rect_6 = CvInvoke.GetStructuringElement(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ElementShape.Rectangle, new Size(6, 6), new Point(3, 3));
    CvInvoke.Erode(skin, skin, rect_6, new Point(-1, -1), 1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.BorderType.Reflect, default(MCvScalar));
    CvInvoke.Dilate(skin, skin, rect_6, new Point(-1, -1), 1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.BorderType.Reflect, default(MCvScalar));
    return skin;
}
```

Here is the result without last 3 lines:
http://prntscr.com/nmvf8n

Here is the result with last 3 lines in action:
http://prntscr.com/nmvflp

And here is the original image on which the above 2 filters were applied:
http://prntscr.com/nmvg47

Notice how I try to avoid the camera myself to get the hand alone, and see how the ceiling objects are also captured as skin.